# Adding a function to shift pieces of a puzzle

Tags: javascript, html, css, puzzle

I want to create a sliding puzzle with different formats like: 3x3, 3x4, 4x3 and 4x4. When you run the code you can see on the right side a selection box where you can choose the 4 formats. Now I want to create a function where I can actually slide/move each piece of the puzzle but right now I have no idea how to make that work. Here is an example of how the puzzle should work: http://www.yash.info/jspuzzle.htm

Since I don't have enough reputation I will post a link to the images here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fIyk.jpg . These images are just placeholders right now.

```js
//jscript:

  function load() {
  var puzzle = '<div id="slidingpuzzleContainer4x4">';

  for (var i = 0; i <= 15; ++i) {
    puzzle += '<img src="images/blank.jpg" alt="blank" width="100" height="100" />';
  }
  puzzle += '</div>';
  showSlidingpuzzle(puzzle);
}


function changeFormat(x, y) {
  var puzzlepieces = [];
  var finalValue = x * y - 2;

  for (var i = 0; i <= finalValue; ++i) {
    puzzlepieces.push(i);
  }

  puzzlepieces.push('blank')
  createSlidingpuzzle(puzzlepieces, x, y);
}


function createSlidingpuzzle(puzzlepieces, x, y) {

  var puzzle = '<div id="slidingpuzzleContainer' + x + 'x' + y + '">';

  for (var puzzleNr = 0; puzzleNr < puzzlepieces.length; ++puzzleNr) {
    puzzle += '<img src="images/' + puzzlepieces[puzzleNr] + '.jpg" class="puzzlepiece" id="position' + puzzlepieces[puzzleNr] + '" alt="' + puzzlepieces[puzzleNr] + '" onclick="shiftPuzzlepieces();" width="100" height="100" />';
  }
  puzzle += '</div>';

  showSlidingpuzzle(puzzle);
}


function showSlidingpuzzle(puzzle) {
  document.getElementById('slidingpuzzleContainer').innerHTML = puzzle;
}


function shiftPuzzlepieces() {

}
```

```css
/**css:**/

body {
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
}

img {
  padding: 0;;
  margin: 0;
}

#slidingpuzzleContainer3x3,
#slidingpuzzleContainer3x4,
#slidingpuzzleContainer4x3,
#slidingpuzzleContainer4x4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#slidingpuzzleContainer3x3 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#slidingpuzzleContainer3x4 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
}

#slidingpuzzleContainer4x3 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

#slidingpuzzleContainer4x4 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.puzzlepiece {
  float: left;
}

#formatContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 500px;
}

#format {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->
<body onload="load();">

  <div id="slidingpuzzleContainer">
  </div>

  <div id="formatContainer">
    select format:<br />
 <select name="format" id="format" size="1" onChange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].onclick()">
            <option onclick="changeFormat(3,3);">Format 3 x 3</option>
            <option onclick="changeFormat(3,4);">Format 3 x 4</option>
            <option onclick="changeFormat(4,3);">Format 4 x 3</option>
            <option onclick="changeFormat(4,4);">Format 4 x 4</option>
        </select>

  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Have you trying using something like jQuery draggble in jquery ui http://jqueryui.com/draggable?

Comment: Blocks must be arrays first. Using Angularjs would be a good way

Comment: @cecilphillip no I haven't tried it but i have no clue of jQuery. Im new to javascript and want just a "simple" solution for javascript where you can for example just click on the piece and it slides to the empty space etc.

Comment: @wZVanG what do you mean with blocks? No idea what Angularjs is. Isn't it possible to keep it realy simple using jscript?

Comment: The movements will be controls or mouse dragging?

Comment: @wZVanG I want it to be with the mouse but not dragging more like after you click on a piece it slides into the empty space

Comment: here is an example of how the puzzle should work http://www.yash.info/jspuzzle.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change `onclick="shiftPuzzlepieces();"` to `onclick="shiftPuzzlepieces(this);"`

This will delete the item when clicked, and adds it to the end:

```
function shiftPuzzlepieces(el) { //Swap function

    var blank = document.getElementById("positionblank"); 
    var temp = el.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement('a'), el); 
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(el, blank); 
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(blank, temp); 
    el.parentNode.removeChild(temp); 

}
```

**Demo**:

```js
//jscript:

  function load() {
  var puzzle = '<div id="slidingpuzzleContainer4x4">';

  for (var i = 0; i <= 15; ++i) {
    puzzle += '<img src="images/blank.jpg" alt="blank" width="100" height="100" />';
  }
  puzzle += '</div>';
  showSlidingpuzzle(puzzle);
}


function changeFormat(x, y) {
  var puzzlepieces = [];
  var finalValue = x * y - 2;

  for (var i = 0; i <= finalValue; ++i) {
    puzzlepieces.push(i);
  }

  puzzlepieces.push('blank')
  createSlidingpuzzle(puzzlepieces, x, y);
}


function createSlidingpuzzle(puzzlepieces, x, y) {

  var puzzle = '<div id="slidingpuzzleContainer' + x + 'x' + y + '">';

  for (var puzzleNr = 0; puzzleNr < puzzlepieces.length; ++puzzleNr) {
    puzzle += '<img src="images/' + puzzlepieces[puzzleNr] + '.jpg" class="puzzlepiece" id="position' + puzzlepieces[puzzleNr] + '" alt="' + puzzlepieces[puzzleNr] + '" onclick="shiftPuzzlepieces(this);" width="100" height="100" />';
  }
  puzzle += '</div>';

  showSlidingpuzzle(puzzle);
}


function showSlidingpuzzle(puzzle) {
  document.getElementById('slidingpuzzleContainer').innerHTML = puzzle;
}


function shiftPuzzlepieces(el) { //Swap function
    
    var blank = document.getElementById("positionblank"); 
    var temp = el.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement('a'), el); 
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(el, blank); 
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(blank, temp); 
    el.parentNode.removeChild(temp); 
   
}
```

```css
/**css:**/

body {
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
}

img {
  padding: 0;;
  margin: 0;
}

#slidingpuzzleContainer3x3,
#slidingpuzzleContainer3x4,
#slidingpuzzleContainer4x3,
#slidingpuzzleContainer4x4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#slidingpuzzleContainer3x3 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#slidingpuzzleContainer3x4 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
}

#slidingpuzzleContainer4x3 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

#slidingpuzzleContainer4x4 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.puzzlepiece {
  float: left;
}

#formatContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 500px;
}

#format {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->
<body onload="load();">

  <div id="slidingpuzzleContainer">
  </div>

  <div id="formatContainer">
    select format:<br />
 <select name="format" id="format" size="1" onChange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].onclick()">
            <option onclick="changeFormat(3,3);">Format 3 x 3</option>
            <option onclick="changeFormat(3,4);">Format 3 x 4</option>
            <option onclick="changeFormat(4,3);">Format 4 x 3</option>
            <option onclick="changeFormat(4,4);">Format 4 x 4</option>
        </select>

  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: i want it so that it slides to the empty space, not always add the clicked piece to the end. aswell it counts the 14th places as the last place but 15th is the last one.

Comment: **Update demo**: There must be an swap function, try

Comment: this is pretty decent now but you can swap pieces diagonal aswell as jump over other pieces into the free space.

Comment: and for some reason when i use a format like 3x3 and after that i use 3x4 it adds up instead of replace the old field why is that?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like homework so I don't want to take the fun of creating a solution away from you.

A simple strategy-
Keep the `puzzlepieces` as a global scope so it can be referenced after populated with pieces. When a piece is clicked on check the four cardinal directions relative to the clicked-tile for the blank tile. If the blank tile is in one of the directions, swap the clicked-on tile with the blank one, if the blank tile isn't found then the piece must be immovable. Also, Watch out for the edges of the board when checking the four directions.

Comment: So you mean adding the "var puzzlepieces = [];" to the top of the code? as a global variable? and this is acutally not homework, im just curious and trying to create a little puzzle.

Comment: Yes, or you could pass the array into the shift function. Just as long as the shift function can access the game board.